# Probability Characteristic Functions

Tags: probability

If $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are independent $\operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ random variables and set $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for $n\geqslant 1$. How can I show that $\frac{S_n}{n} \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$ ?

Comment: What do you know? What have your tried?

Comment: You need to use independence of $\{X_k\}$ to reduce the characteristic function of $S_n/n$ to the product of characteristic functions of $X/n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest approach is to employ the characteristic function:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t \frac{S_n}{n} \right) \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} \right) \right) \stackrel{\text{independence}}{=} \left(  \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i \frac{t}{n} X \right) \right) \right)^n
$$
The characteristic function of the standard Cauchy distribution equals $\mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t X \right) \right) = \exp(-|t|)$, therefore
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t \frac{S_n}{n} \right) \right) =  \mathbb{E}\left(  \exp\left(-\left|\frac{t}{n}\right| \right) \right)^n = \exp\left(-|t|\right)
$$
Since $\frac{S_n}{n}$ has the same characteristic function as $X$, they are equal in distribution, i.e. $\frac{S_n}{n} \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}(0,1)$.

Comment: Should $$
  \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t \frac{S_n}{n} \right) \right) =  \left(  \exp\left(-\left|\frac{t}{n}\right| \right) \right)^n = \exp\left(-|t|\right)
$$ be $$
  \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left( i t \frac{S_n}{n} \right) \right) =  \mathbb{E}\left(  \exp\left(-\left|\frac{t}{n}\right| \right) \right)^n = \exp\left(-|t|\right)
$$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is atypo.